# Unsuccessful read() after successful select() and FD_ISSET()

Tags: c++, linux

In a Linux environment, I have an application that gets a file descriptor from an API call to a driver. The following function is what I use to read the data read in by a card on my system. About 1 out of 10 reads fail. I am puzzled as to why, after a successful select, and checking to see if the read_fd is set, no data is returned.

```
int MyClass::Read(int file_descriptor)
{
    unsigned short read_buffer[READ_BUFFER_SIZE];
    fd_set read_set;
    time_val timeout;
    int return_value = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int status = -1;

    // Initialize read file descriptor
    FD_ZERO(&read_set)

    // Add driver file descriptor
    FD_SET(file_descriptor, &read_set)

    // Set timeout
    timeout.tv_sec = 0;
    timeout.tv_usec = 10000;

    while(!count)
    {
        // Wait for data to be available to read
        return_value = select(file_descriptor + 1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

        // Make sure an error or a timeout didn't occur
        if (-1 == return_value)
        {
            cout << "an error occurred" << endl;
        }
        else if (0 == return_value)
        {
            cout << "a timeout occurred" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            // If the read file descriptor is set, read in the data
            if (FD_ISSET(file_descriptor, &read_set))
            {
                count = read(file_descriptor, read_buffer, sizeof(read_buffer));

                // Double check that data was read in
                if (!count)
                {
                    cout << "read failed" << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Set status to success
                    status = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: `select()` modifies the `fd_set`(s) that you pass it to. You need to reset them on each loop iteration.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added an FD_ZERO(&read_set) and an FD_SET(file_descriptor, &set) call after the else, inside the while loop and I'm still getting failed reads.

Comment: Because you are not handling return values correctly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I implemented your answer below, and while it's handling the error cases better, I'm just getting a bunch of "peer disconnected" instead.

Comment: And? If you don't want those messages logged, then don't log them. But you do need to handle the cases where `select()` and `read()` actually fail, and the case where `read()` returns 0 after `select()` says the socket is readable, which means the peer closed the connection gracefully, so you can't read/write from/to that peer anymore. You need to decide what you want `Read()` to do when the connection with the peer disappears

Comment: Fair enough. No arguments here.

Answer (score 1):

A return value of 0 from read (your `if (!count)` check) does not mean that the read failed -- it means that the read succeeded and got an EOF.

In any case, `select` returning with the file descriptor set does not mean that a read of that fd will not fail -- it means that a read of that fd will not block, and will return something immediately, either failure or success.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `select()` correctly.  It modifies the `fd_set`, and possibly the `time_val`, so you have to reset them on each loop iteration.

Also, you are not handling errors correctly.  `read()` returns -1 on error, 0 on disconnect, and > 0 on bytes read.  You are not handling error and disconnect conditions correctly.

Try something more like this instead:

```
int MyClass::Read(int file_descriptor)
{
    unsigned short read_buffer[READ_BUFFER_SIZE];
    fd_set read_set;
    time_val timeout;
    int return_value, count;

    do
    {
        // Initialize read file descriptor
        FD_ZERO(&read_set);

        // Add driver file descriptor
        FD_SET(file_descriptor, &read_set);

        // Set timeout
        timeout.tv_sec = 0;
        timeout.tv_usec = 10000;

        // Wait for data to be available to read
        return_value = select(file_descriptor + 1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

        // Make sure an error or a timeout didn't occur
        if (-1 == return_value)
        {
            cout << "select failed" << endl;
            return -1;
        }

        if (0 == return_value)
        {
            cout << "select timed out" << endl;
            continue; // or return, your choice...
        }

        // select() returned > 0, so the fd_set MUST be set,
        // so no need to check it with FD_ISSET()...

        // read in the data

        count = read(file_descriptor, read_buffer, sizeof(read_buffer));

        // Double check that data was actually read in
        if (-1 == count)
        {
            cout << "read failed" << endl;
            return -1;
        }

        if (0 == count)
        {
            cout << "peer disconnected" << endl;
            return 0; // or -1, or whatever you want...
        }

        // success
        break;
    }
    while (true);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean now by my error handling, and resetting fd_set and time_val. I'll give this a shot. Thanks!